# Angular 2 - find instance in array

Tags: arrays, angular, angular2-services

Im building a dummy login for an app, and I need to check for an instance of the user logging in, within an array

I have some mock data

```
import { User } from './user';

export const USERS: User[] = [
  {username: 'Seth', password: 'youwillneverknow'},
  {username: 'Peter', password: 'iforgot'},
  {username: 'Frank', password: 'test123'},
];
```

Which I use in my user.service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './user';
import { USERS } from './users.mock';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  getUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(USERS);
  }

  <some method here>

}
```

and in my component I need to write a method checking if the user exists in the array.

```
  logIn(value: string): void {

  }
```

The string value comes from a input field in my HTML

I need some input on how to check for an instance of that username when calling the logIn function

Comment: I doubt you're doing the authentication correctly. With this scheme you would be fetching the passwords from the server.

Comment: As I said.. Dummy login

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find an instance of an array use:

```
users.find(x => x.username == value);
```

This will return the object in the USER array that with the matching user name.  It will return undefined if it doesn't exist.

You can also use `findIndex`, which will return the index of the item in the array that matches the predicate or -1 if it doesn't exist:

```
users.findIndex(x => x.username == value);
```

As for having a list of usernames and passwords, this is definitely not recommended authentication.  I hope you are doing something else for a production application.

Comment: Thanks, it works - but what if I want to search with multiple parameters like `let user = this.users.find(x => username == user, z => password == pass);`
The problem is that this can get the username from one user, and the password from a different user.

Comment: If you want to search with multiple parameters then you'd use `this.users.find(x => x.username == user && x.password == password);`

Comment: That was my first guess but it threw me an error. Ill try again and get back If it fails