# Get Data Through ID in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-directive, angular-services, angular-http

I have a list of purchase orders and i want to have another component that will hold the details of each purchase order. How can i get the details of each purchase order by getting its id? I need to display the material_purchase_orders by getting the purchase_order.id. By clicking the viewDetail(), it will navigate me to the new component and display the specific purchase order detail

> html

```
<div class="card-block" *ngFor="let order of orders">
      <h2 class="proj-name">{{ order.name }}</h2>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Transaction Date</th>
            <th>Reference Number</th>
            <th>Grand Total</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let inner of order.purchase_orders">
            <td>{{ inner.transaction_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ inner.reference }}</td>
            <td> {{ inner.total }} ringgit </td>
            <td><button  type="submit" class = "btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="viewDetail(inner.id)"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  View More Details</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
```

> ts

```
getAllOrders(){
    this.subscription = this.purchaseOrderService.getAll()
        .subscribe(
          (data:any) => {
            this.orders = data.purchaseOrders;
            console.log(data);
          },
          error => {
           console.log(error);
          });
  }

  viewDetail(id){
    this.router.navigate(['orders', id]);
  }
```

> service.ts

```
getAll() {
        if(!this.orders) {
                this.orders = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url)
                                    .map((response => response))   
                                    .publishReplay(1)
                                    .refCount();  

            }
            return this.orders
      }
```

Comment: What is the issue your are facing here? have you added routing for detail view?

Comment: @Dimuthu. Yes i have the routing. The problem is how do i get the data of each purchase order? How can i match the id?

Comment: then you can use service to pass data to detail component and find item by Id,

Comment: ah, then you can user service to send data between component

Comment: @Dimuthu. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to get is an item from a nested array inside an array. I see this could be handled in a few ways.

- You could store the chosen order in a service and fetch it when
  navigating to detail page. Downside is that the data is not available
  on page refresh.
- If you have control of backend, you could do so that the chosen order
  can be fetched from the db directly based on id. (This would be my
  choice)
- If you do not have control of the backend, I see that you need to
  iterate the `orders` and then the `inner` to find the order matching
  this chosen order.

So for the last option, your code should look something like this:

```ts
getOrder(id) {
  return this.getAll()
    .map(data => {
      // iterate the top level
      for (let order of data.purchaseOrders) {
        // find the order
        let ord = order.purchase_orders.find(x => x.id === id)
        if(ord)
          return ord;
      }
    })
}
```

and in your detail component, just like Dimithu, we get the parameter and call `getOrder`:

```ts
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, 
            private purchaseOrderService: PurchaseOrderService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.paramMap
   .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => 
      this.purchaseOrderService.getOrder(+params.get('id')))
        .subscribe(order => this.order = order);
 }
```

### **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n8cvch?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: It says data.find is not a function. I think this is all my fault. In my viewDetail(id), I'm passing the id of  purchase_orders. However in my api, i cannot get to the id of purchase_orders since purchaseOrders is the project. purchaseOrders represents each project and each project has purchase_orders and purchase_orders has its own details

Comment: Yeah, right data is an object right, so it should maybe be `return data.purchase_orders.find(x => x.id === id)` right if I understand correctly. Try that :)

Comment: I got it wrong myself now with the nested object inside object. Updated my answer with the correct changes (I think, haha) so disregard my previous comment and look at answer ;)

Comment: The error now is Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Comment: Please debug and console log all responses you are getting, I think I got the nested objects correct, hmm?

Comment: I added a second image above :)

Comment: Could you just paste the JSON you are getting instead of images, so that I can debug, but you really should also debug yourself and console log your responses along the way to see how your data looks like :)

Comment: I think you must subscribe it in the service the "data.purchaseOrder"?

Comment: not subscribe in service, you cannot return anything from subscribe. It should be like the demo, but the build of your data is different than in demo, and you have only provided images of your data, just paste the JSON response and I can debug it with your data.

Comment: I have added it the JSON just now. Thank you

Comment: Thanks! :) Now I realize that you have a nested array inside an array, was an oversight from me. I would actually skip the `find` altogether perhaps and just store the chosen item in service and fetch it from there. Hold on, I'll look into your code :)

Comment: Updated my answer with demo :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort. By the way, is there a downside for the last option?

Comment: Well, naah. Of course if you have maaaaaany records and it happens to be the last one it takes a while to "find" it. But otherwise no. The big upside to the first option is of course you have the url always available, which is of course what you'd probably want :)

Comment: How can i get "material": {
                "id": 1,
                "sku": "938509",
                "name": "Gwapo",
                "created_at": "2017-10-20 09:23:47",
                "updated_at": "2017-10-20 09:23:47"
              } and display it in the HTML?

Comment: You just need to traverse your data. In what context would you like to get this, it's unclear, you want to always fetch this (if exists) or fetch it for some specific order?

Comment: Yes of it exists. Like, i want to get material.name? Thanks

Comment: Here's demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eck15c?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: If works. but if i refresh page it says Cannot read property 'material_purchase_orders' of undefined

Comment: This probably is an async issue, set `*ngIf="order"` on the whole div, or then `order?.material_purchase_orders` in template, where order is the name of the variable you have named in your detail page. Check this: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Comment: Sir, thanks a lot for your time and effort and sorry if I'm bothering you :). Have a great day

Comment: Hah, no problem, I had time to help today, so why not ;) You have a nice day too and happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

service.ts

add this method to service.ts file

```
 getOrder(id: any) {
        this.orders = this.getAll();
        const selectedOrder = this.orders.find(order => order.id === id)
        return selectedOrder;
    }
```

use parameter reading in detail view using this,

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
  if (params['id'] !== undefined) {
    const id = +params['id'];
    this.navigated = true;
    this.purchaseOrderService.getOrder(id)
        .then(order => this.order = order);
  } else {
    this.navigated = false;
  }
});
```

}

for more details refer into this source code https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-tour-of-heroes/tree/master/src/app

Comment: It says  this.orders.find is not a function

Comment: Please check this - this.orders => this.orders.find(oder => oder.id === id)

Comment: getOrder(id: any) {
        this.orders = this.getAll();
        const selectedOrder = this.orders.find(order => order.id === id)
        return selectedOrder;
    }

Comment: could you please try this, hope you have initialize orders parameter as array.

Comment: It still says this.orders.find is not a function

Comment: if data is inside that this.orders as array it should work, we have used this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157794/angular-2-find-instance-in-array